# Xamarin Forms Change NavBar background image on Specific pages

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Following this tips, ([Xamarin.Forms: how to set background image of NavigationPage bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937501/xamarin-forms-how-to-set-background-image-of-navigationpage-bar))
I change the Navbar bg image.

I can change this image in specific pages? Already exist some custom render for that?

Use various navbar's backgrounds...

Comment: Which specific pages you mean,you can show image.

Comment: like this [image](https://i.imgur.com/a4RmFcD.png)

Comment: Ok,do you try this `NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon (this, "image.png");`?If work ,plaease tell me as the right answer.

Comment: Ohh heyy, not works for me... basically this sets an icon in the center.
A create a grid layout and hide native navbar.

Comment: Ohh, just using custom renderer to do it.(https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44586/navigationbar-background-image-renderer-android/p1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might succeed doing what you want with the new TitleView introduced in Xamarin Forms 3.2 for NavigationPage without any CustomRenderer or platformspecific code.

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView> 
            <Image Source="main_background_image.png" Aspect="AspectFill">
            </Image>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#displaying-views-in-the-navigation-bar